# F#: Why do two ref or boxed values holding equivalent value types equate to the same cell or obj?

Tags: f#, ref

```
let i = ref 123
let j = ref 123
i = j   // true
```

Similarly:

```
let i = box 123
let j = box 123
i = j   // true
```

Presumably, i and j are not actually pointing to the same exact place in memory...??

I get around this (odd?) behavior in the second case by doing:

```
obj.ReferenceEquals (i, j)    // false
```

What is the proper equality test for the first case?

EDIT:

I see that calling obj.ReferenceEquals works in the first case, as well.

Can someone out there explain to me why I have to call this function, though?  Why can't I just use the = operator?

Comment: F#'s `=` uses generic/structural equality, not reference equality.

Comment: I like your question, it think reference equality makes more sense. ML tradition diverges: SML uses reference equality, OCaml structural (unless the specific operator `==` is used). F# appears to follow OCaml in this design.

Comment: @toyvo: Why does reference equality make more sense?

Comment: Because references are mutable. When you use equality, you are typically interested in detecting if two values have the same meaning and are in some sense interchangeable. Structural equality relation on mutable objects is fickle, it depends on when you evaluate the equality test.

Comment: What about immutable types, types with mutable fields that have no bearing on equality, etc? I think the bottom line is _equality is hard_ and isn't defined the same in all situations.

Comment: I just don't like the counter-intuitiveness of expressly instantiating a reference type, then having it *conditionally* compared as a value type, in contrast to how a .NET language (and OO programming in general) normally works.

Of course, I guess I can just do `let (==) _obj1 _obj2 = obj.ReferenceEquals (_obj1, _obj2)` and `let (!=) _obj1 _obj2 = not <| obj.ReferenceEquals (_obj1, _obj2)`, and use those operators.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The (`=`) operator calls [GenericEqualityObj](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/master/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/prim-types.fs#L1475-1504). It first checks the types of the args (for arrays, assignability to `IStructuralEquatable`, and a few other special cases) and the final case calls `obj.Equals`. `Equals` is overridden by `ValueType` (which `int` derives) to do bit comparison. That explains why `(box 123) = (box 123)` is `true`.

Answer (score 3):

Ref cells are represented using [records](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233184.aspx), by default records are structurally comparable\equatable

Comment: This answer reminds me of the [joke about the programmer who was asked to go the the store to get some milk and eggs](http://www.divinecaroline.com/22324/113050-computer-programmer-s-wife-asks-go).  :)

It's technically correct, but what I really want to know is why F# was designed this way, i.e. equality by structure/value and not by reference, when equality by reference is the norm for the other .NET languages.

I got my answer with respect to reference cells (implemented using a type that compares by value), but what about Objects (obj)?  Shouldn't i = box 123 not equal j = box 123 ??

Comment: @MiloDC: `=` calls `Equals` which is overridden for value types to do bit comparisons.

Comment: @Daniel: But `obj` is not a value type.

In C#, `isSame` returns `false`:

    `Object i = 123;
    Object j = 123;
    bool isSame = i == j;`

In F#, `obj` is just an abbreviation for `Object`.

Comment: But given that `Equals` is virtual the override will be called no matter what the static type is. `object i = 123; object j = 123; i.Equals(j)` returns `true`. `==` checks for reference equality by default, unless one of the types being compared provides a custom implementation.

Comment: I see, so you don't actually mean that Equals "is overridden for value types to do bit comparisons"; what you mean is that it's overridden "to support bit comparisons for value types."  Is that right?  i.e. You didn't mean to suggest that obj is a value type (which is how I read your response).

Comment: No, `obj` is not a value type. Virtual dispatch depends on the _run-time type_. It's the same as: `Animal a = new Dog(); a.Bark();` calls `Bark()` on `Dog`, not `Animal`. It's the same with `object i = 123;`.

Comment: "== checks for reference equality by default, unless one of the types being compared provides a custom implementation."  It still bothers me that the same code in F# and C# returns a different Boolean result.  Seeing two reference types (Objects) being equality tested as *value* types in F# was disconcerting.  Anyway, thanks for your input!

Comment: The key is knowing that `==` and `=` are not the same operator. They test reference equality (by default) and structural equality, respectively. So it's not "the same code."